# Bash + Node.js + stdin/stdout redirection: error "not a tty"

Tags: node.js, stdout, stdin, git-bash, mingw-w64

This problem may be Windows-specific. I have not tested it on Linux or Mac.

I use:

- Windows 7 64 Bit
- Node.js 8.1.3
- Git for Windows 2.8.1, including GNU bash, version 4.3.42(5)-release

`node my-cli.js > foo.txt`: Error `output is not a tty`

`node my-cli.js < foo.txt`: Error `input is not a tty`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a file `my-cli`:

```
#!/bin/sh

node "path/to/my-cli.js" "$@"
exit $?
```

Call `./my-cli > foo.txt` or `./my-cli < foo.txt`.

This also works with arguments: `./my-cli --answer 42 > foo.txt`

Comment: Works with git-bash to `./my-cli | grep "something I am looking for"` whereas this returns `input is not a tty` without this additional script file.

Comment: did you figure out why that happens?

Answer (score 18):

This happens because Git for Windows on default setup will source this file `/etc/profile.d/aliases.sh` which will do `alias node="winpty node.exe"`, which is required for interactive usage with `node` (as well as other programs like `python`,...). So when you invoke `node xxx <yyy >zzz`, your shell is actually calling `winpty node xxx` under the hood

> [`winpty`](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty) works by starting the winpty-agent.exe process with a new, hidden console window, which bridges between the console API and terminal input/output escape codes. It polls the hidden console's screen buffer for changes and generates a corresponding stream of output.

, but the side effect is that the stdin and stdout is not recognised as tty's.

So when piping or redirecting, you would want to invoke the `node` binary itself and not the alias. There are some ways to achieve this:

1. Wrap in a shell script which would directly call `node` since non-interactive shell does not source the `aliases.sh` file. See the other answers (both `sh` and `bash` work)
2. Call with
   `env node my-cli.js > foo.txt` or
   `command node my-cli.js > foo.txt`

`env` runs the command in a default environment, the effect is like that of the above method; while `command` is a `bash` shell built-in that is used to bypass aliases.

3. Call like
   `\node my-cli.js > foo.txt` or
   `'node' my-cli.js > foo.txt` or
   `"node" my-cli.js > foo.txt`

The backslash and quotation are constructs to explicitly bypass aliasing.

4. Call using
   `node.exe my-cli.js > foo.txt` or
   `/full/path/to/node my-cli.js > foo.txt` or
   `relative/path/to/node my-cli.js > foo.txt`

The alias is for `node`, not `node.exe` nor `path/to/node`, which still points to the actual binary.

A way to expand on these solutions is to write a wrapper script that detects [piping](/questions/911168/how-to-detect-if-my-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe)/[redirection](/questions/9340129/test-stdout-and-stderr-redirection-in-bash-script) (which is in itself a whole other challenge tbh) which will decide to use `winpty` or not.

Comment: As far as I did understand, on Git Windows **node** command for e.g. **node** file_name.js invokes itself through aliased **winpty** resulting in side effects of I/O redirections / piping being unrecognized as a part of tty, right ? Whichever the case would be it really helped to understand the idea a bit on how things work under the hood . Thanks @Phu Ngo ♥ !

Answer (score 4):

Since I'm here in 2022 having this same issue in GitBash, one of the other answers pointed me to the simplest solution.

Since you're already typing

`node my-cli.js > foo.txt`

All you need to do is change `node` to `node.exe` and leave everything else the same.

`node.exe my-cli.js > foo.txt`

The aliases answer above is what made me try this. `node` is aliased, but `node.exe` is not aliased, so it works the way you want it to work.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, it solved a problem !

Answer (score 1):

`sh -c 'node my-cli.js' > foo.txt` works for me