# A shell script to check the version of NodeJS doesn't work in Git Bash on Windows

Tags: node.js, bash, git

I am trying to make a shell script to automatically download, compile and build some program I've made. You can see the full script [on my blog](https://flatassembler.github.io/AEC_specification.html#AEC_to_WebAssembly). My program requires NodeJS 11 or newer, so I am trying to make my script output an appropriate error message in case it's not installed. Here is what I've tried:

```bash
node_version=$(node -v) # This does not seem to work in Git Bash on Windows.
# "node -v" outputs version in the format "v18.12.1"
node_version=${node_version:1} # Remove 'v' at the beginning
node_version=${node_version%\.*} # Remove trailing ".*".
node_version=${node_version%\.*} # Remove trailing ".*".
node_version=$(($node_version)) # Convert the NodeJS version number from a string to an integer.
if [ $node_version -lt 11 ]
then
  echo "NodeJS version is lower than 11 (it is $node_version), you will probably run into trouble!"
fi
```

However, when I try to run it in Git Bash on Windows 10, with NodeJS 18 installed and in PATH, here is what I get:

```
stdout is not a tty
NodeJS version is lower than 11 (it is 0), you will probably run into trouble!
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is a mismatch in expectations of how a terminal should behave from a program with unix/posix expectations compared to how terminals behave on windows. This is a known problem, and there is a longer discussion of the issue on the [nodejs repository](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3006) (although this is not unique to just nodejs).

To compensate there is a tool [winpty](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty) which provides the missing expectations (or alternatively [node-pty](https://github.com/microsoft/node-pty)), although you normally do not need to install explicitly, it should be included in the normal Git bash installation.

For this reason `node` is normally set up to be an alias for `winpty node`, although that causes [problems for stout/stdin redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60776006/23118), so a common practice is to then invoke node as `node.exe` (e.g. `node.exe --help | wc -l`) to sometimes avoid using winpty.

For your case you probably want to change your script to

```bash
if ...is-running-on-windows... # Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/38086185/23118
then
    # I expect one of these to work
    NODE_BINARY=node.exe
    NODE_BINARY="winpty node"
else
    NODE_BINARY=node
fi
node_version=$($NODE_BINARY -v)
```